# Joomla - Could not connect to MySQL - "Sometime"

Tags: mysql, joomla

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.
```

This Error is shown sometimes (one every 20 pageviews) and I tried a lot of solutions without any change.

This error found with Joomla 3.5+

Comment: Did you check your code have closed the session after using it?

Comment: Does your MySql Server have lot of traffic? Please try "show processlist;" to check how many connections are open. You may need to increase MySql Server's connection limit. OR something like @Genuine suggested, are Joomla sessions closing properly? session_write_close() will also close database connections if open.

Comment: @Genuine I didn't use session_write_close() or any sessions functions on my coding, I don't have any idea if you can explain more.

Comment: @rsharpy  I found SQL VARIABLES max_connections=151 in my server, I think that's the problem because I read max_connections =2000 is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server RAM was very low!

After upgrade from 0.5GB to 2GB all the kind of error starts with `Error displaying the error page:` gone.

I found the problem solution by using `htop` while connecting to the server via SSH, after that, I start opening pages rapidly which show the error plus the htop shows that the RAM was close to full.

`show  processlist;` were helpful to find that the problem not about the connection number.which it may sometimes cost the same error in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you do some testings...

On MySql server run this query...

```
show processlist;
```

If this shows a lot of connections then you may be hitting the max_connections problem. Try to increase that to a reasonable number. But, do not make it too much because if it goes beyond the amount of available resources on your server then it will make MySql server crash and it will become a bigger problem where your website will go offline.

Try to check if you are closing sessions properly in your scripts using session_write_close(); You can find more about this function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php
This function will write user's current session on disk to be reloaded next time and most important part it will do for you with this problem is that it will close PHP's any connection made to the MySql server, so it will free up the MySql server for next visitor to come and open another page.

Lets say if you have 150 max_connections and at the same time you get 200 visitors, then PHP will still wait for some time for another 50 connections to be free before giving a timeout error where you get "Could not connect to server". But, if sessions are not closing properly, then its so bad that 50 connections will never get processed because 150 will never go away very soon, there is a separate MySql setting for that named wait_timeout. So, any MySql connection you open will keep waiting until you close yourself in script just like you open OR until wait_timeout happens. But, if you close sessions properly then next connection will become available as soon as your PHP script has finished processing and page is generated for the user for viewing and it will make the connection seat free for next connection to come in.